# Evaluate vectors or tuples in a function (julia)

Tags: julia

I want to evaluate a set of vectors (or tuples) in a function $f$ but Julia says me that is imposible.

For example: If I have an array of tuples `p=[(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)]` and a function `f(x,y)=x+y`. I would like to calculate `f(p[1]) = f(1,1)= 2`. But Julia says me that the types are incompatible.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to splat a tuple like this:

```
julia> p=[(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1)
 (1, -1)
 (-1, 1)
 (-1, -1)

julia> f(x,y)=x+y
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(p[1]...)
2
```

you could also define a higher order function `splat` that would conveniently wrap any function and perform splatting. It is useful as then you can e.g. broadcast such function:

```
julia> splat(f) = x -> f(x...)
splat (generic function with 1 method)

julia> splat(f)(p[1])
2

julia> splat(f).(p)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  0
  0
 -2
```

Alternatively you can define your function `f` like this:

```
julia> f((x,y),)=x+y
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(p[1])
2
```

and now you do not have to do splatting.

Comment: [`Base.splat`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/715e6264e33a408a576966dc9ca2a75ddc4cc160/base/operators.jl#L1150) (which is unexported, though).

Comment: Ah - right. I did not remember what was the conclusion from discussion of adding it to official API.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `...` operator to unpack the tuple as parameters:

```
julia> f(p[1]...)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, if your task allows you, you can just define

```
julia> f(x) = f(x...)
```

and use it as

```
julia> f.(p)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
  2
  0
  0
 -2
```